# Allow one External User in Office 365 to send email to a Distribution list

Tags: email, azure-active-directory, cloud, office365, distribution-list

I'm a global administrator of my O365 account - I have an external user who is not in our O365 contact list and needs to send email to one of our O365 distribution group and I don't want to check mark on "allow external user to send to this Distribution list" as I don't want every external user send to that distribution list - my question is how do I can grant permission just to that one external user to send email to the distribution list who is not added as an O365 contact and where distribution list has a restriction to not receive email from external users.

Comment: Did not test it but what if you add the external user into the tenant as guest user and add it into the Distribution list group?

Comment: that user is already a guest user in our tenant, sorry I didn't mention before User don't want to get every email sent by this DL - User just want to send email to this DL, so I'm not adding that user into the distribution list group also I can't check mark on allow external user to send email as we don't want every external user start sending email to this DL.